# The set of permutations of the positive integers is uncountable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

My textbook says that the set of permutations of the positive integers is uncountable. I want to prove this but my mind's completely blank. How do I write a proof for this?

Comment: You could possibly assume there is an injection between the set of permutations of positive integers and the natural numbers and show a contradiction? I don't know if it will work but that would be my first attempt.

Comment: Can you build an injection of the powerset of the positive integers into your set?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider $\mathbb N$ in pairs: $\{1,2\},$ $\{3,4\},$ $\{5,6\},\dots$ Think of the permutations on $\mathbb N$ that are a permutaion on each such pair. On each pair $\{2n-1,2n\},$ such a permutation will either switch $2n-1$ with $2n,$ or will leave the pair alone. The set of all such permutations can naturally be identified with the set of binary sequences.

Comment: This is really the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to write this as a comment but can’t do presently. But you can see this by making a diagonal argument akin to standard one used to show that the real numbers are uncountable.

*Added Later*:

The (accepted/first, see also Brian’s) answer of following post [Is symmetric group on natural numbers countable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321653/is-symmetric-group-on-natural-numbers-countable) contains the diagonal argument I was trying to intimate in my comment/answer. (Apologies for not providing this detail earlier in my comment/answer).

Comment: You have to show that the diagonal is a permutation again.

Comment: Can you give more detail?

Comment: Yes, I can. I actually learnt/read a proof even here on math.stackexchange or math overflow a few years ago. I’d just recall or look it out. (I’d like to know if my not providing details is the reason for a downvote on this post/comment; if any advice, I’d appreciate it. I’m new here and may not be aware of some things). Thanks

Comment: @Peter and SeraPhim: I have provided the details by referencing the original source where I had learnt this some time ago.