# Is $\{f \colon \mathbb{N}\mapsto\mathbb{N}: f \text{ is a bijection}\}$ numerable?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $A :=\{f \colon \mathbb{N}\mapsto\mathbb{N}: f \text{ is a bijection}\}$. Is $A$ numerable?

I don't know how to attack this problem, but I think that this set is not numerable. However, I can't see how to start the demonstration.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321653/is-symmetric-group-on-natural-numbers-countable

Comment: What would Cantor do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is symmetric group on natural numbers countable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321653/is-symmetric-group-on-natural-numbers-countable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $X\subset \Bbb N$ such that both $X$ and $\Bbb N\setminus X$ are infinite, we can define an $f\in A$ by letting $f$ map the $k$th smallest element of $X$ to the $k$th smallest element of $\Bbb N\setminus X$ and vice versa.
To see that $|A|\ge|\mathcal P(\Bbb N)|$, note that for every subset $Y$ of $\Bbb N$ we can pick $X=3Y\cup (3\Bbb N+1)$ to obtain a different $f$ for every choice of $Y$.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow the part about picking $X=3Y\cap(3\mathbb{N}+1$... Can you please explain that part a little bit, please? Sorry for bothering you...

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Find an injection of the powerset $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ into $A$. Now apply [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem).