# Show that $S_{\mathbb{N^*}}$ isn't countable.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $S_{\mathbb{N^*}}$ be the set of all permutations of $\mathbb{N^*}$. Show that $S_{\mathbb{N^*}}$ isn't countable.

Let $f : \mathbb{N^*} \mapsto S_{\mathbb{N^*}}$ be a bijection. I introduced
$$
\sigma(k)
=
\begin{cases}
\min
\{
l \mid l\neq f(k)(k) \text{ et } l \neq \sigma(i) \, \forall i \in [1,k-1]
\} ,&\text{if }k>1\\
\min
\{
l \mid l\neq f(k)(k)
\} &\text{if }k=1\\
\end{cases}
$$
It's clear that $\sigma$ is injective, but I don't know how to show that it's surjective. Do you have any hint?

Comment: It is likely clear from context for most, but I am not familiar with the definition of $\mathbb{N}^*$, could you define it for me please?

Comment: @RyanK Yes, $\Bbb {N^*} = \Bbb N \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: How would this help you? To prove that a set $X$ is uncountable, you must prove that there *cannot* exist a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $X$.

Comment: @HansHüttel If $\sigma$ is bijective, it's easy to see that $\sigma \not \in f(\mathbb{N^*})$, so $f$ isn't surjective, which is absurd.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321653/is-symmetric-group-on-natural-numbers-countable

Comment: Try give it a look. It should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your $\sigma$ need not be surjective without some conditions on $f$. Suppose that $f(k)(k)=1$ for each $k\in\Bbb N^*$; this is certainly possible. Then $1$ cannot be in the range of $\sigma$.

Your $\sigma$ **will** be surjective if $f$ has the property that $\{k\in\Bbb N^*:f(k)(k)\ne m\}$ is infinite for each $m\in\Bbb N^*$. If not, let $m=\min(\Bbb N^*\setminus\operatorname{ran}\sigma)$. If $\sigma(k)=n>m$, then either $f(k)(k)=m$, or $\sigma(i)=m$ for some $i<k$. The latter is impossible, so $f(k)(k)=m$ for all but finitely many $k\in\Bbb N^*$, is impossible if $\{k\in\Bbb N^*:f(k)(k)\ne m\}$ is infinite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By introducing $\sigma$, I wanted to use a similar argument as Cantor's diagonal argument for this question. Do you know if there's another function $\sigma$ that uses this idea (and is bijective of course)?

Comment: @Michelle: You’re welcome. The accepted answer to [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321653/is-symmetric-group-on-natural-numbers-countable) to which **Adriano Banchieri** linked in the comments uses a diagonal argument, though it’s version of $\sigma$ is very different from yours.